# Slice pandas series for each list in a list without using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series which I want to slice based of list of slice-indices. It's fairly easy using list comprehension like

```py
slizes = [[0,1,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
series = pd.Series(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"])
[series.iloc[slize] for slize in slizes] #[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],...]
```

But since I have 1.5 mio rows and 1.5 mio slices this takes quite a while. I was wondering if it could be done in a faster vectorized-way?

The result could be anything from numpy-arrays, list, Series, tuples, that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) **if you have always the same size of sublists**, just slice:

```
a = series.to_numpy()
out = a[slizes]
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['e', 'f', 'g'],
       ['h', 'i', 'j']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Aaaah of course,!